# Android Huawei P30 Lite - unconsistent value for getDimensionPixelSize, getDimension & applyDimension

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

## Context

The application I'm working on has a medical purpose. The objective is to display some elements on the screen with predefined sizes in mm. Then we ask the user to do some action on them. The size in mm significantant.

## Problem

I have defined dimensions in my project. Example :

```
<dimen name="one_millimeter">1mm</dimen>
```

In order to display these elements, I use `getDimensionPixelSize`, `getDimension` & `applyDimension` to have a value in Px (my screen display pixels).

If I use them on the dimension I defined above on a Huawei P30 Lite I have the following output :

```
getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.one_millimeter)      // 16
getDimension(R.dimen.one_millimeter)               // 21.17...
applyDimension(COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 1f, displayMetric) // 21.17...
```

I know that `getDimensionPixelSize` returns an `Int`. I know that `getDimension` & `applyDimension` returns an `Float`. It is well documented in the documentation.

**But I can't explain why I have more than a 23% difference on the integral part (`16` vs `21`).**

In my case, I need a float value. But in my case the `21` values are wrong. It should be `16.13253656...` (as an example).

In my understanding, these methods are SDK methods. So my conclusion is that there is a problem with the implementation provided by the vendor.

## Question

1. Am I missing something? Are you agree with my analysis?
2. If yes, Is there something I can do to fix it?